# Visualise Hbase in Azure HDInsight with Power BI

Tags: azure, powerbi, connection, hbase, azure-hdinsight

Can i connect power bi to Azure Hdinsight directly? And how do i do go about doing it?

I have tried googling online but there isn't any article with clear instruction on this. It is deploy under azure Vnet as well.

Answer (score 0):

> As of today, Azure HDInsight HBase is not supported to connect Power BI.

I would suggest you to vote up an idea submitted by another customer.

https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=9d8134df-19be-4608-80df-0b08f9c140d4

https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=9c08cf4a-7326-493f-bff2-3967f305b6ca

All of the feedback you share in these forums will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams responsible for building Power BI connectors.